# Regex to match n characters after last /

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match 10 chars after last backslash `/` in a URL.

- Example input `https://www.facebook.com/reel/1a1c6e99h60a3169h86816`
- Output should be `https://www.facebook.com/reel/1a1c6e99h`
- Example input `https://www.facebook.com/reel/1a1c6e99h60a3169h86816/`
- Output should be `https://www.facebook.com/reel/1a1c6e99h`

Used this regex `([^/]*$)` to select everything after last `/`

- But this way getting last path & truncating it later will be overhead.
- It's better if I can select URL from starting to and of last / with 10 chars.

This is what I've tried [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/7812h)

Comment: What should be the output in case of `https://www.facebook.com/reel/1a1c6e99h60a3169h86816/123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead with `.*`:

```
.*/.{10}
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/30VnFioua276Gy).

The `.*` is greedy, so the matched `/` will be the last slash. Slashes at the end aren't matched because there aren't 10 chars after it.

Comment: Also is there a way to negate this like selecting remaining text.

Comment: The remaining text is matched by `(?<=/.{10})[^/]*$`

Comment: I've asked another question can you help me with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75455589/get-n-chars-after-last-in-url-path